# $H^s(\mathbb{T})$ space is a Banach algebra with pointwise product

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I have ran across the following theorem but the given proof does not convince me.

**Theorem** Let $u, v \in H^s(\mathbb{T})$ with $s>1/2$. Then the pointwise product $uv$ is in $H^s(\mathbb{T})$ and $\lVert uv\rVert_s \le C\lVert u\rVert_s\lVert v \rVert_s$ for a constant $C$ not depending on $u$ and $v$.

In functional terms, this theorem is telling us that $H^s(\mathbb{T})$ space is a Banach algebra when $s>1/2$.

> **Question** Can you provide a reference for the proof of this theorem?

---

The proof which I was given begins writing

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\lVert uv\rVert_{H^s}&=\left\lVert \sum_{k_1+k_2=k}\langle k \rangle^s \hat{u}(k_1)\hat{v}(k_2)\right\rVert_{\ell^2}\\
&=\left\lVert \sum_{k_1+k_2=k}\frac{\langle k \rangle^s}{\langle k_1\rangle^s\langle k_2\rangle^s} \hat{u}(k_1)\langle k_1\rangle^s\hat{v}(k_2)\langle k_2\rangle^s\right\rVert_{\ell^2}\\
&=\left\lVert \sum_{k_1} A(k_1, k-k_1) \hat{f}(k_1)\hat{g}(k-k_1)\right\rVert_{\ell^2},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $A(k_1, k_2)=\frac{\langle k_1+k_2\rangle^s}{\langle k_1\rangle^s\langle k_2\rangle^s}$ and $\hat{f}(k_1)=\hat{u}(k_1)\langle k_1\rangle^s, \hat{g}(k_2)=\hat{v}(k_2)\langle k_2\rangle^s$. Then using triangle and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalites one proves that 
$$
\lVert uv\rVert_{s}\le \lVert A(k_1, k_2)\rVert_{\ell^\infty_{k_2}\ell^2_{k_1}}\lVert u\rVert_s\lVert v \rVert_s.$$
However, it seems to me that this proves nothing since 
$$\lVert A(k_1,k_2)\rVert_{\ell^\infty_{k_2}\ell^2_{k_1}}=\sup_{k_2}\lVert A(\cdot, k_2)\rVert_{\ell^2} \ge \lVert A(\cdot, 0)\rVert_{\ell^2}=\infty.$$

How can one repair this?

Comment: Is the conclusion really necessary for the sequel? The reason I ask is that a much more natural argument, using the "trace theorem", says that, since  $u\otimes v\in H^s(\mathbb T^2)$, restricting to the diagonal (=multiplying) loses $1/2+\varepsilon$, so $u\cdot v\in H^{s-{1\over 2}-\varepsilon}$ for $s>1/2$.

Comment: See [Sobolev space is an algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314820/sobolev-space-is-an-algebra).

Comment: @user74737: Thank you very much for the link. Looks like the reasoning exposed there can be adapted without differences to Sobolev spaces on toruses.

Comment: @paulgarrett: This is a very nice little argument for sure!