# Is Sobolev space $H^{s}(\mathbb R),$ for $s>\frac{1}{2},$ closed under point wise multiplication?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

We note that, $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ is not closed under point wise multiplication.

Let $s>\frac{1}{2};$ and we define Sobolev space, as follows:
$H^{s}(\mathbb R)=\{f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R):[\int_{\mathbb R} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2}(1+|\xi|^{2})^{s}d\xi]^{1/2}<\infty \}.$

> **My Question is**: Is Sobolev space $H^{s}(\mathbb R),$ for $s>\frac{1}{2},$ closed under point wise multiplication, that is, if $f,g \in H^{s}(\mathbb R),$ can we expect $fg\in H^{s}(\mathbb R)$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/314820/8157

Comment: This holds for the torus too, in case you need it: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/374650/8157