# Composition operators on fractional-order Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, function-and-relation-composition

**Preliminaries:** We know that the fractional-order Sobolev spaces $\mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{T})$ are closed under multiplication provided $s > 1/2$. This is proved for example in the following questions using the Fourier convolution theorems:

- [Sobolev space is an algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314820/sobolev-space-is-an-algebra)
- [For which $s \in \mathbb{R}$, is $H^s(\mathbb{T})$ a Banach algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821818/for-which-s-in-mathbb-r-is-hs-mathbb-t-a-banach-algebra?lq=1)

Thus we infer that $u^p \in \mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{R})$ for all $p \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ whenever $u \in \mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{R})$. Similarly for $H^s(\mathbb{T})$.

**Question:** Is there a simple argument to conclude that $u^p \in \mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{R})$ for all interpolating values $p \in [1, \infty)$, too?

More generally, from a [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/178344/68629) it is stated that the composition $f \circ u \in \mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{R})$ for all real-valued $u \in \mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{R})$ provided $f \in \mathrm{C}^{\lfloor s + 2\rfloor}(\mathbb{R})$ with $f(0) = 0$. I would like to see references to this result or an outline of a proof.

**Revised question:** As pointed out by Joonas Ilmavirta below, I had made an elementary mistake concerning the expression $u^p$ for $p \in (1, \infty) \setminus \mathbb{Z}_+$, which should have been $|u|^p$ instead. Then I ask:

> For which $p \in (1, \infty) \setminus \mathbb{Z}_+$ and $s > \frac{1}{2}$ is $|u|^p$ or $u|u|^{p - 1}$ in $\mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{T})$ whenever $u \in \mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{T})$?
>
> (Similarly for $\mathrm{H}^s(\mathbb{R})$, but the periodic case is most important.)

Note: $|\cdot|^p \in \mathrm{C}^{\lfloor p \rfloor}$ for $p > 1$.

Comment: The result you quote from the MO question implies that $\lfloor p\rfloor\geq2+\lfloor s\rfloor$ is enough for the implication $u\in H^s\implies |u|^p\in H^s$. I don't know how sharp this is, but I suspect you cannot do significantly better.

Answer (score 2):

The claim you wish to conclude is false. Pick $u\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ so that $u(0)=0$ but $\nabla u(0)\neq0$. If $p\geq1$ is not a natural number, then there is $s>0$ so that $u^p\notin H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ (because classical derivatives fail to exist to orders above $p$) although $u\in H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ for all $s$. This works in any dimension, including $n=1$.

There is, of course, also the problem of defining $u^p$ for many values of $p$.
The conclusion above is valid, no matter how you define $u^p$ for $u<0$ (you can take any of $|u|^p$, $-|u|^p$ and $0$), since $x\mapsto x^p$ is not smooth.

Comment: Thank's @Joonas Ilmavirta for pointing out the problem's error. I have revised the question.