# Sobolev multiplication theorem

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I would like to know whether multiplication defines a bounded map
$$H^{1/2} \otimes H^{1/2} \to H^{-1/2}$$
dimension of the domain is $3$.

I have checked two different sources and one said that it works but the other that this map is bounded as a map 
$$H^{1/2} \otimes H^{1/2} \to H^{s}$$
where $s < -\frac{1}{2}$. That is why I am confused.

Notation: $H^{1/2} = W^{1/2, 2} = L^2_{1/2}$

I would be satissfied with a source i can rely on.

Answer (score 1):

For $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ there are Sobolev embeddings
$$
H^{1/2} \subset L^3, \, L^{3/2} \subset H^{-1/2}
$$
where the second one follows from the first one by duality. Thus
$$
f, \, g \in H^{1/2} \subset L^3 \; \Rightarrow \; fg \in L^{3/2} \; (\text{by Cauchy-Schwarz}) \;  \Rightarrow \; fg \in H^{-1/2} \, .
$$

Answer (score -1):

See [this notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/254a.1.01w/notes3.ps) by Terry Tao. Also, [Sobolev multiplication below the borderline](http://tensorial.com/math/gauge/sobolev.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for interest. Unfortunetelly notes by Terrence Tao doesnt give an answer. The second link i have checked earlier and it gives positive answer. However no refferences are given and the proof is for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ which is not my case. I need something i could cite in the paper.

Comment: @BigBolzano, I will search more in my books.

Comment: @BigBolzano, read the answer by paul garrett in http://math.stackexchange.com/users/52330/frank-zermelo.

Comment: Thanks. The answer given there proves that $H^{s} \times H^{s}$ gives a well defined element in $H^{s-\frac{3}{2}}$ but the assumption is $s - \frac{3}{2} > 0$ which is not my case (cannot give the same argument). Also $\frac12-\frac{3}{2} = -1$ but this does not say that the element is not in $H^{-\frac{1}{2}} $ (which would be stronger). I am trying to find a counterexample maybe.

Comment: @BigBolzano, I've found this: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X00972093.

Comment: (The above mentioned answer of p. garrett is presumably this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315044/80734)