# Follow-up question on $H^s$ space forming an algebra when $2s>n$

Tags: inequality, jensen-inequality

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314820/sobolev-space-hs-mathbbrn-is-an-algebra-with-2sn/315086#315086), the top answer did the following

> $$
> \begin{split}
> (1+|\xi|^2)^p
> &\leq (1+2|\xi-\eta|^2+2|\eta|^2)^p\\
> &\leq 2^p(1+|\xi-\eta|^2+1+|\eta|^2)^p\\
> &\leq c(1+|\xi-\eta|^2)^p + c(1+|\eta|^2)^p,
> \end{split}
> $$
> for $p>0$, where $c=\max\{2^{p},2^{2p-1}\}$.

I am not sure how was the final inequality established. Am I missing some important identity to see this inequality?

P.S. I would usually just ask this in the comment but since that question has been answered about to a decade ago, I figured it'd be better if I ask in a separate post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use that $(a+b)^p \leq 2^{p-1}(a^p + b^p)$. See [Showing the inequality $|\alpha + \beta|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|\alpha|^p + |\beta|^p)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap).